# jqplot bar chart & some series

Tags: jqplot, bar-chart

by using jqplot, I would like to do one bar chart [like this](http://picturepush.com/public/11972509)

I did see the ex. on [the jqplot site](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/) but unfortunately not found
thanks a lot
best regards

Comment: i have just received my friend's helps but i don't know what i have to do now?

Comment: Folowing this [link](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php), take a look at the third example.
The needed option in your case in `stackSeries`